# Nature of $(\ln a)h(x)=(\ln(a^{\large\langle a^{|x|sgn(x)}\rangle})+\ln(a^{\large\lfloor a^{|x|sgn(x)}\rfloor}))$

Tags: calculus

If $$\def\sgn{\mathop{\rm sgn}}f(x)=a^{\langle a^{\large|x|\sgn(x)}\rangle},\quad g(x)=a^{\lfloor a^{\large|x|\sgn(x)}\rfloor}\qquad\text{for } a>0,a\ne1,x\in\mathbb R$$
where '$\langle\,\cdot\,\rangle$' and '$\lfloor\,\cdot\,\rfloor$' are fractional and floor functions.
Now, $$(\ln a)h(x)=(\ln(f(x))+\ln(g(x)))$$
Is h even/odd, and when is it increasing/decreasing?

---

I am able to convert:
$$h(x)=a^{|x|}\sgn(x)\ln a$$ 
Which i can say is odd function
It might be wrong.Now it is so complicated, i cannot diffrentiate, how to tell increasing/decreasing nature.
It must be odd and increasing for all a.

Comment: Please do not use displaystyle math in question titles.

Comment: @AlexR word taken

Comment: Also, do reserve `<` and `>` for inequalities in math. Use `\langle` and `\rangle` for $\langle$ and $\rangle$ (pet peeve of mine, with apologies for said peevishness).

Comment: @Aditya No need to fully rollback to how it was really bad. Reverted to your notation but corrected all formatting issues.

Comment: please everybody don't try your hand at editing, it is good as it is by @AlexR

Comment: I arrive at $h(x) = a^{|x| \sgn x} = a^x$...

Comment: Why are you using $\vert x\vert · \sgn (x)$ instead of simply $x$?

Comment: @DarthGeek I also didn't notice until AlexR because I just carried what was written in question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I arrive at
$$h(x) = \log_a (a^{\langle a^x \rangle}) + \log_a (a^{\lfloor a^x \rfloor}) = a^x$$
With monotonicity decreasing on $\mathbb R$ if $a\in (0,1)$ and increasing on $\mathbb R$ if $a > 1$.
Note that I used $x=|x|\sgn x$.

Comment: minor error in my work, feeling ashamed :(

Answer (score 1):

You need the following general rules: 
$$\begin{align}\log_a Z&=\frac{\ln Z}{\ln a}  \\
Y&=\log_a a^Y \\ 
x&=|x|\cdot\sgn(x)\\
W&=\langle W\rangle + \lfloor W\rfloor
\end{align}$$

Comment: I used all this, that's why i have written: "i am able to convert"

Comment: I get a much simpler expression. How did you get $\sgn(x)$ seperate from $|x|$? They are always multiplied, so you didn't use $x=|x|\sgn(x)$. Also, it is unclear how you got a $\log a$ in the right side.

Comment: soory you were right